# Drawing vertical line with axvline()

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've been attempting to draw a vertical line on my bar plot, yet, am having hard time finding out the right X value where `XPos = np.arange(13)`,
`Subplot1.set_xticks(XPos+1)`. Here, you may take a look at what I've got.
Many thanks in advance.

```
Subplot1.axhline(3, xmin=0, xmax=0.25, ls='-', lw=1 , color='navy')
Subplot1.axhline(6, xmin=0.25, xmax=0.75, ls='-', lw=1 , color='navy')
Subplot1.axhline(9, xmin=0.75, xmax=1, ls='-', lw=1 , color='navy')

Subplot1.axvline(???, ymin=3, ymax=6, ls='-', lw=1 , color='navy')
Subplot1.axvline(???, ymin=6, ymax=9, ls='-', lw=1 , color='navy')
```

[image]

Comment: There is a dog eating a finger in the link you posted. Can you please upload the image through the image uploading function here? Apart, I do not understand the problem at all. Where do you want the line to be, and what hinders you in using that position instead of `???`?

Comment: Many thanks for your prompt reply. and my apologies for being naive...I cant seem to find the uploading function here. Please add this bar() function before the axhline()  and axvline() calls above. There are 13 bars numbered 1 to 13 and am trying to draw a vertical line between columns 3-4 and columns 10-11 limited by ymin=3, ymax=6 and ymin=6, ymax=9 as given in axvline() function above. `Subplot1.bar(XPos=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13], Y=[4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,1,2,3,12,13], 
width= 0.8)`. Hope this helps.

Comment: [Upload image](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post). Maybe you are overthinking this? A line in data coordinates between two points is simply a `ax.plot`. So `ax.plot([3.5, 3.5], [3, 6])`? In contrast, an `axvline` is useful when you want to positon the line in axes coordinates in the vertical-, but data coordinates in the horizontal direction.

Comment: Thanks a million. Your hint helped a lot, though, I didnt quite get how come axvline() wouldn't work out here.